# Rename txt files with ADODB without creating a new one

Tags: excel, vba

my problem: I have many text files that I want to rename. 
I have been using the ADODB.Stream object to open/read/write the files because they are encoded in UTF-8. So now, if possible, I want to rename the files without the workaround of copying their content, writing their content into a new file with the desired name and deleting the old one. The time stamp on the documents is a valuable information for me, which is why I do not want to create new files.

here is my current workaround that creates new files and deletes the old ones.
Issues with the code:
1) Copied files have new time stamps
2) New Lines don't get copied into the new lines. As they contain some kind of XML code, the generated files become hard to read. I would need to write a piece of code that sets new lines on all appropiate positions after copying.

```
        Sub renameModules()
        Dim currentTXT As Variant, newTxt As Variant
        Dim currentPath As String, newPath As String
        Dim currentContent As String
        currentPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\MyCurrent.txt"
        newPath = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\Target001.txt"

        Set currentTXT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        currentTXT.Charset = "utf-8"
        currentTXT.Open
        currentTXT.LoadFromFile (currentPath)
        currentContent = currentTXT.ReadText()

        Set newTxt = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        newTxt.Charset = "utf-8"
        newTxt.Open
        newTxt.WriteText currentContent
        newTxt.savetofile newPath, 1

        Kill currentPath

        End Sub
```

For simplicity I have only included the essential steps and omitted all error handling.

My goal: Finding some method to simply rename the current file without fiddling with its content.

Comment: Why not just renaming the file? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Comment: wow I feel so stupid, thank you very much for your advice. For some reason I cannot mark your post as the answer.

Comment: Because it's just a comment. Just mark FunThomas' answer as good ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to deal with `ADODB.Stream`: You can use the VBA command `name` not only to rename a file but also to move it to a different folder:

```
Name currentPath As newPath
```